# How to create two themed version of a community site?

Tags: community, community-builder, experience-cloud

I am trying to create a community cloud site that has a light-themed version and a dark-themed version.

What I tried is,

Create a page variation for each page for the light theme. The default variation is for the dark theme. We have a special audience who will use the light theme.

Can it be done in this way? Because I can not set two different background colors of a **compact header**  component in two page variations.

I am also trying to create a custom theme layout and mimic the **compact header** component.

What can be the approach here?